# Boot issue: APCI Error - AE_NOT_FOUND while resolving a named reference package

Tags: boot, acpi

Its been working fine up until a couple days ago when it stopped booting altogether and just shows

```
AE_NOT_FOUND while resolving a named reference package

PV1D
PV06
PV01
PV13
PV09
PV0D

20220331/dspkginit-438
```

[image]

I have read a few help posts about this and a number of them point to a BIOS issue. I have updated the BIOS according to this advice but it has no effect on the problem

Other users were able to boot to a different kernel. I have not been able to boot with any of the following:

```
5.19.0-42
5.19.0-41
5.19.0-40
5.19.0-38
5.19.0-35
5.19.0-32
```

Machine is an HP Z2 G5

Other advice suggests putting disks in IDE mode. This device does not have that option in BIOS.

Can anyone help with what I might try next to try and get this system working again?

Comment: Chances are that the APCI errors are not the problem here. I’d try booting into a live environment and running fsck on your root partition. Would also be worth checking to see if any partitions are full. You could also look at the logs from the live environment to see what that shows. If you have any data that you cannot afford to lose back it up before you do anything.